# Suppress DeprecationLevel.ERROR in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I’m using [DeprecationLevel.ERROR](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-deprecated/index.html) in my APIs:

```
@Deprecated(
    message = "moved to def()",
    replaceWith = ReplaceWith(expression = "def()"),
    level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
fun abc() = def()
```

I want a test to ensure callers see this replacement. For example, my test should fail to compile if I accidentally delete the `abc()` method.

But I can’t find a way to make this compile:

```
@Test
@Suppress("something")
fun deprecatedAbc() {
  abc()
}
```

For example, `@Suppress("DEPRECATION")` doesn’t work. Is there something that does?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [`DefaultErrorMessages`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/diagnostics/rendering/DefaultErrorMessages.java), you can use `@Suppress("DEPRECATION_ERROR")`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-deprecated/index.html#kotlin.Deprecated) of `@Deprecated`:

> To help removing deprecated API gradually, the property level could be used. Usually a gradual phase-out goes through the "warning", then "error", then "hidden" or "removed" stages:
>
> - First and by default, `DeprecationLevel.WARNING` is used to notify API consumers, but not to break their compilation or runtime usages.
> - Then, some time later the deprecation level is raised to `DeprecationLevel.ERROR`, **so that no new Kotlin code can be compiled using the deprecated API**.

Code *does not compile by design* -- and `@Suppress` only suppresses warnings, not errors (see [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-suppress/)).

So, what you are trying to achieve is not possible. Also, it seems to me as if you're testing a Kotlin feature, rather than your business logic. You might instead try to test the *behavior* of the replacement.

Comment: Thanks! FWIW I am trying to assert about my own exported API. Sample PR if you’re curious: https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/5044